# 1031 exchange and cash boot

Tags: united-states, taxes, home-equity, 1031-exchange

My question is about 1031 exchange and whether I can get rid of the mortgages from my life once and for all, by investing only with the equity I got? Looks like this great idea is not possible.

The question is: Can the replacement property be around 400K, or is it that it must be worth 850K, and I must end up with a new 450K mortgage?

Answer (score 1):

The key element of a 1031 is that you are replacing the property with on at least as expensive. Any cash pulled out creates tax issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is doable the amount not used in the exchange is subject to taxation based on this description:

> A 1031 Exchange allows a taxpayer to defer 100% of their capital gain
> tax liability.  To do this, the exchanger must buy new Replacement
> Property equal to or greater than in value to the property sold and
> reinvest all of the proceeds from the sale of their old property.
>
> But what happens if a taxpayer desires to purchase property lower in
> value or takes a portion of the cash from the closing of the sale and
> only invests a portion of their proceeds towards a 1031 Exchange? The
> good news is that these transactions still qualify for tax deferral
> under Section 1031 of the Tax Code. They simply become “partial” 1031
> Exchanges where the taxpayer has a partially tax deferred transaction
> rather than deferring all of their taxes.
>
> The portion of the exchange proceeds not reinvested is called “boot”
> and is subject to capital gains and depreciation recapture taxes.

taken from this site:
https://www.ipx1031.com/partial-exchange/